# Windows does not update when connected to internet via usb tethering, although everything else is. Solution?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, usb

Here is what I am using:

Dell inspiron 7000 touch enabled laptop, x64, windows 10.
samsung tab E 9.6 inch
usb cable

After connecting the tab to the port via usb, I get the internet as soon as I check the **enable usb tethering button.** I can browse and download but cannot update the windows. It recognizes the connection in the information section but does not update the windows when I click update. I tried downloading the updates manually, which it successfully did, but the installation said the file was not compatible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you didn't set it to be a "metered connection" or alternatively that you allow updates over metered connections.

Comment: Your carrier may also be block windows updates to prevent data usage complaints.

Comment: @Nobody it wasnt set to metered plus i have allowed updates over metered connections.